# How do you set global properties for child tasks in Spring Cloud Dataflow using Stream - Task-Launcher-Dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a stream with an Http source, custom processor and Task-Launcher-Dataflow
[image: Spring Cloud Dataflow Stream]

I have a composed task the gets called from the stream - task-launcher-dataflow

[image: SCDF Composed Task]

I pass several properties in the stream processor to the task-launcher-dataflow and to the child tasks, example...

```
deploymentProps":{"app.composedtask-filecopy2.prescript.scriptFile":"/source/prescript.sh"}
```

This works fine but I have reached the maximum character limit and get a sql exception on the composed task pod stating I have exceeded the 2500 character limit. I would like to set properties for all tasks instead of individually to save space on characters but using a wildcard character doesnt work

```
deploymentProps":{"app.composedtask-filecopy2.prescript.*":"/source/prescript.sh"
```

Is there a way to set properties for all tasks instead of having to set them individually?

I tried setting these in the Spring-Cloud-Dataflow-Server configmap in kubernetes, specifically for the imagePullPolicy but so far this hasnt worked.

[image: SCDF Configmap]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SCDF 2.8.x you can try the following deployer property.: `deployer.*.kubernetes.image-pull-policy=Always`

Comment: Thanks Glenn, this appears to be working!

Comment: On second look this is not working, one of the strange things I have discovered with SCDF is that if you run a task manually with arguments/properties it will keep those properties (in the database) and use them on future executions. The way we figured this out was on a new scdf database creation, those global * properties no longer work, had to go back to setting them individually for each sub task.